# Do quasicrystals exhibit topological order?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, topological-order, quasicrystals

According to the book [Quantum Information meets Quantum Matter](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02595), ordered phases can either be described by a Landau free energy: symmetry-breaking ordered phases; or there are different ways in which local Hamiltonians can give rise to global patterns: topological order.

Quasicrystals don't seem to be symmetry-breaking, at least not the translational symmetry.

On the other hand, they seem to be somewhat analogous to Spin Liquids, which are an example of a topological order; On the other hand, I find it hard to assign a 'topological invariant' to them.

So what kind of order do quasicrystals exhibit?

Comment: I don't know about topological order, but there at least seems to be literature considering quasicrystals as higher-order topological insulators.